# Estimate potential distance from population mean given only sample size?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample

Let say I am sampling from a population with an unknown distribution to approximate the mean of the population.

I am trying to figure out how large my sample size *n* has to be in order to guarantee with 95% confidence that my sample mean is within, say, 1% of the population mean.

I know I can get the 95% confidence interval of the sample mean if the standard deviation $\sigma$ is known, with:

$\bar{X} \pm \frac{1.96\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

But $\sigma$ requires knowing population parameters like $\mu$.

Is there a way to estimate a confidence interval for the mean if I only know $n$?

Comment: Here is an exercise to consider:  suppose with $k>1$ you have independently $P(X_i=k)=\frac1 k$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-\frac1k$ independently over $i$.  Clearly $E[X_i]=1$.  How large a sample do you need to have a $95\%$ probability that $0.99 \le \bar X \le 1.01$?  Note that this will increase with $k$

Comment: For this exercise, your  $\bar{X} \pm \frac{1.96\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ expression might suggest you need a sample size of $n \ge 38416(k-1)$, which while not precise is indeed the correct order of magnitude and higher than most people might guess.  As this increases with $k$, there can be no guarantee.

Comment: In general you estimate the confidence interval from the dispersion in the sample, often by using the sample standard deviation.